# jQuery: if php function did exit, then do something

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a form that triggers a PHP function via the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('#subnewtideform').submit(ajaxSubmit_subnewtideform);

function ajaxSubmit_subnewtideform(){

    var subnewtideform = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: subnewtideform,
        context: this,
        success:function(data){
            // it's successful, do stuff
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

It works fine. The problem is that I want to do something else if the php function `exit;` or `return;`.

For example:

```
success:function(data){
    // it's successful, do stuff
} else {
    // the function returned, so do something else
}
```

The `else` statement above will be triggered when the ajax call fails... not when the php function has `exit/return`.

How can I make the jQuery code understand that my php function has `exit`?

Comment: why don't you send an error status code like 404?

Comment: You need to put it in the response and filter the response using the jQuery.

Comment: you could send a variable for example `$exit='exit'; echo $exit;` via php right before the `exit()` function and in you ajax check if the variable is set `if(data!='exit'){ //normal situation }else{ //exited }`

Comment: @IagoMelanias Can you please demonstrate how I would do that?

Comment: Ok, i'll do something.

Comment: You can do what Amin explained, basically that is it.

Comment: @IagoMelanias I tried to echo 'success'; and in my jquery function, I do if(data=='success') {} but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Is that the only information is being printed in the screen? Use the `console.log` and check in the inspector what is the exactily response is being returned in the variable `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery ajax function has an `error` callback function for this exact scenario:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: subnewtideform,
    context: this,
    success:function(data){
        // it's successful, do stuff
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err){
       // Ajax failed/error
    }
});
```

See [the docs for ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) too to see what has been deprecated and to also see what other functions are available (done, fail, always).

Answer (score 0):

The success part of the jquery ajax function is related to the request status. as it says on the documentation

> A function to be called if the request succeeds.

What you can do on your php is to return a value that you can check on your success function. For instance you can return a json object with something like `{"exit":true}`.